# What is the name in english of dancing like this

Tags: idioms

How can I call in english when a woman dance like using a hoola hoop? 
( obviously without really using one )

Comment: I think gyrating, as said below, is the closest. However, "belly dancing" is similar.

Comment: "belly dancing" is not what I looking for. Her hips must perform a circle with a little throw of her foot in beggining of movement. I can't find anything on youtube.

Answer (score 1):

You could say *her hips are gyrating*.

To gyrate is to move in a circular manner.  The word comes from the greek for a circle, the same root as gyroscope.

Unconnected with hula hoops, Elvis Presley was said to gyrate his hips on stage.

Comment: I'll youtube for this to see if it's what I'm looking for and post the result. Thanks. This movement is sexy when she throws one leg (or foot) forward when complete the circle.

Comment: I can't find anything similar on youtube with "gyrating" term. All of finds shows hula hoops. I think this kind of dance is not specific. Even in brazilian portuguese we just call "rebolar", wich is generic term for dancing moving hips.